# Disable Same Origin Policy in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, mobile-safari, same-origin-policy

I have an HTML5/JavaScript app that was originally written to run in certain cars.  Basically, I need to set up my app to run in the browser for a simple demo to a customer.

I'm using jQuery .ajax which is causing problems due to the Same Origin Policy.  I have found plenty of ways to disable this in desktop browsers, but not mobile ones.

My goal is to demo the app on an iPad in Mobile Safari.  Is there any way to temporarily disable the Same Origin Policy on an iPad?

Comment: +1, I would love an answer to this too.

Comment: Have you tried setting the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * on the server?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the server I am making AJAX calls to.  My short-term solution was to host a php proxy script on the same server that I hosted my html/js on.  Fortunately, the services I needed finally added CORS headers to their responses which allowed me to do away with my proxy script.

Comment: Currently (today) there is no other proper solution rather than setting the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *". Your client side solutions won't satisfy you. Another way is using JSONP (=changing your communication way). All these solutions are already postet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a sencha app. I resolved by setting a base path to my javascript ajax calls, example:

```
var BASEPATH = 'http://192.168.1.200/myapp';

$.ajax({
  url: BASEPATH+'/someaction'
});
```

And from the mobile I access it with `http://192.168.1.200/myapp`

My problem was that the from mobile I get access only with IP but ajax call were point to localhost.

Hope this trick helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a web server, not the file protocol.

Comment: It would have to be running on a web server to even access from the iPad in the first place.

The problem is that I have no control over the services that I call, which do not include CORS headers in their responses.  The solution that I came up with was to host a php proxy script on the same server as my html/js.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need a header.

Put this code at the top of the page you want to send cross domain requests to.

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>
```

Be careful with the *, as this allows any website to send requests to the page from which that header is sent from.

The * can be replaced with domains, such as example.com, example.net.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JSONP in your ajax call. It will bypass the Same Origin Policy.

http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Answer (score -1):

It can be possible in Javascript if you use an ajax call to a public proxy which basically removes the same origin header. Or you could write a php curl get page where you make the call to using ajax. For code on this check this blogpost:

http://thewebtimes.tumblr.com/post/90549614884/access-forbidden-webpages-with-javascript