# CORS blocks one API request (not others) in Safari

Tags: node.js, safari, axios, cors, access-control

I am running a React (16) webapp (deployed on Netlify) that is failing with one if its API calls being blocked by CORS but only in Safari. There's no problem in Chrome or Firefox. The console shows the following:

```
Origin https://chicha.netlify.app is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://chicha-api.herokuapp.com/votes due to access control checks.
Failed to load resource: Origin https://chicha.netlify.app is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Headers of the blocked request (Safari):

```
Summary
URL: https://chicha-api.herokuapp.com/votes
Status: —
Source: —
Initiator: 
xhr.js:178


Request
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: https://chicha.netlify.app
Referer: https://chicha.netlify.app/events
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Safari/605.1.15
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Response
No response headers
```

Here are the headers of the same request that is not blocked (Chrome):

```
Request URL: https://chicha-api.herokuapp.com/votes
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: 52.214.138.78:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://chicha.netlify.app
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2020 10:43:59 GMT
Server: Cowboy
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Via: 1.1 vegur
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,es;q=0.9,ca;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: chicha-api.herokuapp.com
Origin: https://chicha.netlify.app
Referer: https://chicha.netlify.app/events
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36
```

The app makes the call with axios configured as followed:

```
class ApiClient {
  constructor() {
    this.apiClient = axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URI,
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' },
    });
  }

  getVotes = () => this.apiClient.get('/votes');
  getEvents = () => this.apiClient.get('/events');
...
```

The API (Node.js with Express deployed on Heroku) has the following CORS configuration:

```
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_DOMAIN],
    })
);
```

... where `FRONTEND_DOMAIN` is `https://chicha.netlify.app` in environment config vars on Heroku.

What's strange is other API requests have no issue. API headers of a successful request (Safari):

```
Summary
URL: https://chicha-api.herokuapp.com/events
Status: 304 Not Modified
Source: Memory Cache
Address: 52.215.119.172:443
Initiator: 
xhr.js:178

Request
GET /events HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: https://chicha.netlify.app
Accept-Language: en-gb
If-None-Match: W/"c010-APRvUYTowK2az7ovB1dPcY+SGuk"
Host: chicha-api.herokuapp.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Safari/605.1.15
Referer: https://chicha.netlify.app/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Response
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
ETag: W/"c010-APRvUYTowK2az7ovB1dPcY+SGuk"
Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2020 10:26:18 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://chicha.netlify.app
Content-Length: 0
Vary: Origin
Server: Cowboy
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Does the fact that the blocked request has a referrer which is distinct from origin matter? Or perhaps some issue with the cookie not being sent with the request (despite the `withCredentials` configuration in axios)?

EDIT (4 Jun 2020): I've been able to replicate this on localhost, so I'm editing to indicate it's just an issue in Safari. Given related questions  and some testing I believe this has to do with the `allowedHeaders` / CORS `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` configuration and maybe the way Safari configures `OPTIONS` preflight request. I haven't been able to see all the request details even configuring Reactotron and apisauce.

EDIT (7 Jun 2020): so I've noted cookies aren't being set in Safari, so the currentUser I set into express on the server side is not persisting (in req.session.currentUser where I set it after login). Also while I was able to produce the error at one point in localhost I am not able to reliably replicate it locally.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Safari was blocking the cookie sent from my API as a result of the "Prevent cross-site tracking" option in Safari privacy settings. Disabling this and everything works perfectly.

So it seems the only workaround is to place the API on the same domain as the web app, or to use a proxy, as referenced in this question and answer:
[Is there a workaround for Safari iOS "Prevent Cross Site Tracking" option, when issuing cookies from API on different domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56972162/is-there-a-workaround-for-safari-ios-prevent-cross-site-tracking-option-when)

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: The following answer only applies to `localhost` development, not for when this issue also happens on a remote server. It's a temporary solution in development mode.

Well, if someone else finds this question, there's an easy fix in Safari. First, make sure you have your Develop menu in the menu bar by going to "Safari" -> "Settings" and in the tab "Advanced" select the option "Show Develop menu in menu bar". Once this is done, you should see the Develop menu. Now, select "Develop" -> "Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions".

[Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions in Develop menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhZ5u.png)

Comment: This may be an option during testing or development. Requiring endusers to disable security measures is certainly not an option when going into production ...

Comment: Oof, you're right. Sorry, I was looking for a solution to this issue in localhost and I must've confused my tabs. I will edit my response.